# Microsoft provider for Oracle and positional parameters

Tags: oracle, ado.net

Is there a way to use positional parameters when calling Oracle stored procedure using System.Data.OracleClient?

IDataParameter parameter = dbCommand.CreateParameter( );
parameter.Value = "Blah Blah";
parameter.Type = OracleType.Varchar;
dbCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);

The code above creates a parameter and assigns "Parameter1" name to it. When stored proc is called Oracle gives "wrong number or types of arguments" error.

Comment: What is the signature of the stored procedure ? What technicality prevents you from naming your parameter ?

Comment: We have a lot of legacy code relying on parameters been positional, not named

Answer (score 1):

Solved problem by switching to provider from Oracle (Oracle.DataAccess)